# ¿Cómo utilizar funcion MAX(), MIN() en SQL?

Tags: php, while, bucle-for, foreach

no llevo mucho programando y me surgió una duda referente a los bucles, tengo un caso especifico en **php** con el que me estoy armando un lio, explico brevemente:

Tengo una serie de datos (horarios) ordenados por fecha, cada fecha contiene 4 horarios distintos: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener el horario menor (más temprano), y el mayor (más tarde) de cada fecha. Tengo algo de codigo estructurado, pero solo es para obtener los valores presentados en la imagen. 
¿qué bucle me sugieren usar, me ayudarían con un ejemplo?
Gracias.
Codigo que tengo a traves de una consulta en MySQL

```
<?php
require "conex.php";

$sql = "SELECT concat(hora, '-', empleado) FROM registro WHERE empleado=001 
order by hora asc";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

foreach($result as $valor){
    foreach($valor as $celda){
            list($fecha, $id)=explode('-',$celda); //listo y creo $fecha,$id 
            $date=$fecha; //crea variable $date
            list($date_s, $hora)=explode(' ', $date );//listo fecha y hora
    }
 }
 mysqli_close($link); 
 ?>
```

esta es la estructura de los datos en mi BD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84505/discussion-on-question-by-artes-cual-bucle-deberia-usar-while-for-foreach).

Comment: Por que no ejecutas las consultas "SELECT max(hora) FROM registro" y "SELECT min(hora) FROM registro"? No entiendo porque utilizas un bucle

Comment: Pensaba utilizar un bucle porque paracía la manera más sencilla de recorrer los datos y obtener un **MIN** y un **MAX**, sin ambargo con la ayuda de @A.Cedano pues se pudo hacer a través del query, si gustas ver como quedo fijate en chat que esta posteado el en primer comentario, saludos.